# Embedding Python in Multi-Threaded c# Applications

Tags: c#, python, multithreading, python-embedding, python.net

My application provide python plugin system.In order to invoke python from c#. I have written a C wrapper of embedding python dll. You can find the gist here **[C wrapper gist](https://gist.github.com/qianlifeng/8123612)**.

Then I use P/Invoke in C# to invoke the C dll. Like this:

```
[DllImport("PyWinAlfred.dll")]
private extern static IntPtr ExecPython(string directory, string file, string query);
```

It's ok if I didn't exec above codes in multiple threads created by C#. The problem is if I didn't use thread, main thread in c# will be blocked while the python codes takes a long time to execute.
Here is the C# multiple thread code I use:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
{
   ExecPython(directory,file,query);
});
```

So, I tried to add multiple thread support in C wrapper code. As you can see in that gist. I tried to add:

```
// Create GIL/enable threads
PyEval_InitThreads();
PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

//python codes

PyGILState_Release(gstate);
```

But this doesn't work for me. When I create some threads to invoke that dll, I will get an exception.

I also tried following codes. Still didn't work.

```
PyThreadState* state = PyThreadState_Get();
// Once in each thread
PyThreadState* stateForNewThread = PyThreadState_New(state->interp);
PyEval_RestoreThread(stateForNewThread);

//python codes

PyEval_SaveThread();
```

I was wondering if this is because I put `Py_Initialize();` in every invoke. When thread2 execute the `Py_Initialize();` will clear all infos that thread1 may requires. I tried to invoke `Py_Initialize()` when my application starts, so it will be invoke only once. But didn't work. Looks like these two calls are totally isolated in p/invoke calls.

I'm poor in C and embedding python, does anyone has related experience? My project hosts in https://github.com/qianlifeng/WinAlfred If you guys want to see the codes I described above.

Comment: This might not exactly be what you want, but embedding IronPython into a .NET application is far easier than CPython. The downside is that there are some Python libraries that won't work well with IronPython.

Comment: I have tried Ironpython, as you said, some libraries won't work well with it. e.g. requests. This why I am now trying CPython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I find http://pythonnet.github.io/. You can find details in this project [WinAlfred](https://github.com/qianlifeng/WinAlfred). I solved the multiplethread issues in this project.

Comment: can you point wox code where multihreading is used with pythonnet?

Comment: @denfromufa did you find where the multithreading is?